# Multi C compiler #warning message

Tags: c, warnings

I have some code which I am developing to compile on both MS Visual C 2010 compiler and an Embedded ARM compiler. Also I want to print some warnings at compile time to remind me that I have some testing code in place. Unfortunately MS do messages with #pragma instead of #warning so I can't just use the same pre-processor directive in both compilers.

I could do this every where:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
 #pragma message("Something to say....")
#else
 #warning "Something to say...."
#endif
```

But it would be nicer to have a macro encapsulate this, eg:

```
#define ccWarnMessage(m)   \
    #ifdef _MSC_VER \
     #pragma message(m) \
    #else \
     #warning m \
    #endif
```

This does not work but is there a way to do it in a neat way ?

Answer (score 0):

I would not use warnings for it. As I see you use IDE so it is much easier to use comment tokens for example TODO. It is transparent to the compilers, does not mess in the source code and IMO is more convenient. You have some predefined tokens and you can create your own ones.

**warnings** should be left for warnings

[image]

Comment: I guess this works for VS IDE, not so sure about the Keil IDE !

Comment: it works in the eclipse as well. Keil is a specific case and code is barely portable.